# Elastic search to get the values from a field

Tags: json

I need to get the value from a particular field and display it using elastic search without any other details. Here is some example data:

`hits: {
    total: 1160
    max_score: 1
    hits: [
        {
            _index: restaurants
            _type: restaurant
            _id: beijing-express-dafna
            _score: 1
            _source: {
                key: beijing-express-dafna
                misc: {
                    latLong: 25.3258600000,51.5308300000
                    closedOrOpen:
                    payement:
                    openTime: 10 AM to 10 PM
                    cost: QR 80 for two people (approx.)
                    address: Food Court, Doha City Center Mall, Dafna, DohaQatar
                    rating: 3.3
                }
                name: Beijing Express Restaurant, Dafna
                features: [
                    Bar Not Available
                    Serves Non Veg
                    Dine-In Available
                    No Home Delivery
                ]
                cuisines: [
                    Chinese
                ]
                __v: 0
            }
        }
}`

I just need the key value so what do I do?

Comment: What keys do you do you want to get? Is it in javascript? And please fix your json. Its not vaild.. Like _name: Beijing Express Restaurant, Dafna_ needs to be _name: "Beijing Express Restaurant, Dafna"_

Comment: yea i just need the restaurant name...no this is the result which i get when i give my index and type name